# XCode - Referring to a UIImageView variable through another string variable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, nsstring

Is it possible to use a string variable to refer to a `UIImageView` variable and change the image? The string variable is created by adding an "s" to the start of the tag of the button pressed. This is also the name of a specific UIImageView.

So one of the `UIImageView` declared in the .h file looks like this:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *s11;
```

And in the .m file so far:

```
NSString *lastpressnum = [@(sender.tag) stringValue];
NSString *lastpressed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s%@", "s", lastpressnum];
[lastpressed setImage:image];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KVC is the tool you need.

```
UIImageView * theImageView = [self  valueForKey:lastpressed];
[theImageView setImage:image];
```